# Interceptors and Apache Camel

Tags: interceptor

I am new to camel so my question is  how to get request and responce values that is displayed on saop UI to the log file using Interceptors configuration. I need to apply some interceptor configuration before the request hit to camel so that we can filter the request object and same with the responce.

Answer (score 0):

Look at logging interceptors in camel cxf endpoint declaration : inInterceptors

http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html

Or

You can just print the request inside your route as well using ${body}

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your route configuration:

```
interceptFrom()
    .when(exchange -> isToBeIntercepted(exchange)) //which routes are to be intercepted
    .process(doSomeStuffHere());
```